# How to convert string = "[a, [b, c, [d, e], f]" to a_list = [a, [b, c, [d, e], f] in python?

Tags: python, string, list, hierarchy, brackets

Basically, I need to convert automatically a python list structure all in string format to a python list structure, without string format.

```
string = "[a, [b, c, [d, e], f]"
a_list =  [a, [b, c, [d, e], f]
```

If it was just this simple case, I could make it by hand. But I have more than 20000 txt files with all verb conjugations in my language, and I need to import them to python.

Comment: Can you show an example of actual input, and the desired output?

Comment: In your example, the number of [ and ] are different. Did you miss a closing ]?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast
string= '[a, [b, c, [d, e], f]'
lists=ast.literal_eval(string)
```

From the docs:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`.

Comment: This gives me an "EOF while parsing" error, probably because the brackets aren't balanced. If I add a closing bracket at the end, I still get an exception.

Comment: @TurePålsson, because ```a,b,c,d,e...``` are not defined. They are not strings. But since OP is reading from files, it will be a string type, so it won't give an error

Comment: I don't think I'm following. Could you edit the example into something that actually runs?

Comment: @TurePålsson the 'string' list is now a proper list. ```[a, [b, c, [d, e], f]]```. But, ```a,b,c,d,e,f``` are not defined. Nor are they strings or integers. That's an error. So you get an exception

Answer (score 0):

I come out with the following solution which is based on the regular expression package, `re` from the standard library.

```
import re

def string2list(string):
    # add quotes around each character
    s = re.sub(r'([a-z])', r'"\1"', string) # only for small characters
    # execute the string as if it were a python command
    return eval(s)

string = "[a, [b, c, [d, e], f]]"
s_list = string2list(string)
print(s_list)
print(s_list[1][-1])
```

Output

```
['a', ['b', 'c', ['d', 'e'], 'f']]
f
```

I answered to the abstraction of your problem, but if in your true application you need to replace more complex stuffs than single characters then you need to find a better regular expression... since the strategy is the same.

! you forgot a closing bracket in your statement: `string = "[a, [b, c, [d, e], f]"` !